# Blockchain based Identity Management System

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to start Identity management system using hyperledger but don't know how to take a start,either from hyperledger-composer or hyplerledger-fabric.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to achieve this with Composer you should work through the [tutorials](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials) to gain some background information, then look at the various [sample models](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-models/tree/master/packages) in Composer, and the [sample applications](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-applications/tree/master/packages).

For Fabric there are [tutorials](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html) for background information.

There are also many links on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Hyperledger Indy for identity related blockchain implementation.

Comment: definitely... it would be unwise to try to develop a new bespoke identity management system. There is already a project designed just for that.

Comment: I don't think it would be unwise, as on one technology there can be same sort of product but different flavors or approach. Anyways specially regarding your question, both composer and fabric has their own advantages. On one hand with composer you start development pretty quickly but it's not development ready as of now, while with fabric you can have more control over the data and it's production ready. So at first try both at basic level and once you get a good understanding of both, you can choose the right path for your implementation, depending upon the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction.